# The homotopy pullback of a point along itself is the loop space

Tags: cohomology, higher-category-theory, loop-spaces, homotopy-type-theory

I have seen on the nLab that we can [view the loop space as a particular homotopy pullback](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/loop+space+object), and that it is even the way a "loop space object" is defined in general (when it exists).

Can someone give me some intuition of why it is so? 
To which construction in geometry does this correspond (up to homotopy)?

Any reference would also be welcome.

Comment: Very informally, the homotopy pullback of $X \times_Y Z$ is the space of triplet $x \in X$, $z \in Z$ and an isomorphism/path/homotopy from $x$ to $z$ in $Y$. In the case where $X$ and $Z$ are just points it is hence basically the space of isomorphism/path between these two points. And if the two points are the same, it is the loop space.

Comment: The point is that an homotopy limit  almost the same thing as a limit, i.e., a compatible sequence (a subobject of the product). The difference in this case is that the elements of this sequence don't need to be compatible in the sense of equality but only up to a path (and you have to include the path on this data). More formally, you substitute every morphism by the mapping path space and take the limit. Or better, take the fibration replacement and then the limit.

Comment: Oh yes, you are both right. If anyone else in the future needs this, the intuition is made precise here: https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/%28infinity%2C1%29-pullback
Thanks to both!

Comment: Another way of seeing this: you know that the circle S^1 is a suspension; in particular, it is a homotopy pushout. The space of based maps out of this (i.e., the loop space) is therefore a homotopy pullback. Writing this out precisely gives the desired description of the loop space as a homotopy pullback.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be seen from the following general formula$^1$ for homotopy pullbacks of topological spaces.

**Proposition.** Let
$$X\xrightarrow{f}Z\xleftarrow{g}Y$$
be a diagram of topological spaces. Then
$$\mathrm{hocolim}\left(X\xrightarrow{f}Z\xleftarrow{g}Y\right)=\frac{X\times Z^{[0,1]}\times Y}{\left((x,\alpha\colon [0,1]\rightarrow Z,y)\ \middle|\ f(x)\sim\alpha(0)\text{ and }g(y)\sim\alpha(1)\right)}.$$

**Corollary.** Let $(X,x_0)$ be a pointed space. Then the loop space of $X$ is the homotopy pullback of the diagram
$$*\hookrightarrow X\hookleftarrow*,$$
where the inclusion maps send the one-point space $*$ to $x_0$.

*Proof.* We have
$$\mathrm{hocolim}(*\hookrightarrow X\hookleftarrow*)=\frac{*\times\mathrm{Hom}\left([0,1],X\right)\times *}{\left((*,f\colon[0,1]\rightarrow X,*)\ \middle|\ f(0)\sim f(1)\sim x_0\right)}\cong\frac{\mathcal{L}X}{\left(f\in\mathcal{L}X\ \middle|\ f(0)\sim f(1)\sim x_0\right)}=\Omega X.$$
(Here $\mathcal{L}X$ is the unbased loop space of $X$.)

---

$^1$See Section 2.1 of [these notes](http://www.staff.science.uu.nl/~meier007/TMF-Lecture.pdf) by Lennart Meier.

Answer (score 2):

Here are some asides on my other answer.

On general loop space objects: See the discussion around (specially above) [Remark 1.1.2.6, [HA](http://www.math.harvard.edu/~lurie/papers/HA.pdf)] and [Section 2.3.2, [Mauro Porta's master thesis](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByJtAd7Hyh5XNGxCdVdiRlJfMnM/view)].

---

Similarly, the suspension of a topological space $X$ is the homotopy *pushout* of the diagram:
$$*\hookleftarrow X\hookrightarrow *.$$

What follows is about the *unreduced* suspension of $X$.

For unpointed topological spaces, we have the following formula$^2$ for homotopy pushouts of topological spaces:
$$\mathrm{hocolim}\left(X\xleftarrow{f}A\xrightarrow{g}Y\right)=\frac{X\coprod(A\times[0,1])\coprod Y}{\left((a,0)\sim f(a)\text{ and }(a,1)\sim g(a))\right)}.$$
Picture from Dugger:

[image]

(Unreduced!) suspension of $S^1$ from Wikipedia:

[image]

---

$^2$See Example 2.2 of [Dugger's A Primer on Homotopy Colimits](https://pages.uoregon.edu/ddugger/hocolim.pdf).